# Create a page process to hide a region

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm having some problems creating a process to hide a region in pl/sql.
Can anyone give a example of how to do it?

Tanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide a region in pl/sql"?  You can hide it with Javascript or Dynamic Actions, or you can conditionally not render it at all by setting a condition on the region.

Comment: I was trying to do it conditionally in the region but this is not working. I created a item `:P1_HIDDEN` and then in a process i do this to put a value in it `DECLARE
a NUMBER;
b NUMBER;
BEGIN

select count(1) into a
from TN_HISTORY_ITEMID 
where itemid in (select id from TN_TREE where pid = (select id from tn_tree where pid =:P1_ID)); 

select count(1) into b from surv_host_data where id_client = :P1_ID;
if b <> 0 AND a = 0 then
    :P1_HIDDEN := 3;
elsif a = 0 then
    :P1_HIDDEN := 3;
elsif b = 0 then
    :P1_HIDDEN := 3;
else 
    :P1_HIDDEN := 3;
end If;
End;` but isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If appropriate, you can put the PL/SQL you need directly into the Condition, using the Condition Type "PL/SQL Function Body Returning a Boolean".  For example (using your code from above, which doesn't seem quite right to me - all roads lead to hidden=3!):

```
DECLARE 
 a NUMBER;
 b NUMBER;
 hidden NUMBER;
BEGIN
 select count(1) into a from TN_HISTORY_ITEMID where itemid in (select id from TN_TREE where pid = (select id from tn_tree where pid =:P1_ID));
 select count(1) into b from surv_host_data where id_client = :P1_ID;
 if b <> 0 AND a = 0 then hidden := 3;
 elsif a = 0 then hidden := 3;
 elsif b = 0 then hidden := 3;
 else hidden := 3;
 end If;

 return (hidden = 3);
End;
```

If you need to do it with a process and a page item, then you need to make sure that the item is rendered before the region, and that the process runs before the region to be hidden is rendered.  Otherwise by the time the item is set it will be too late.

Comment: Yes that was a error when doing past and copy. But with that i cant set the value of `:P1_HIDDEN` with a value.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - `:P1_HIDDEN := 3;` does set the value of P1_HIDDEN.

Comment: I have that item without any value and with a process want to set a value to it. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Start with the simplest possible process: `:P1_HIDDEN := 3;`.  That will set it to the value '3'.

Comment: Ok, but i have done that and when i show the item in the aplication is empty. Can it be because of the time of rendering of the process and the item?

Comment: Yes, if the item is rendered before it is populated then you will see it without the value.

Comment: Tanks again for your help  :)